# Custom Webhook Receiver in .Net big-commerce

Tags: bigcommerce, asp.net-webhooks

I'm trying to create webhooks receiver for bigcommerce webhooks.

```
public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext 
  context)
        {
            string action = context.Actions.First();
            JObject data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();
            var dataAsString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            return Task.FromResult(true);

        }
```

my function not hit.

Comment: Hi, can you provide more context? Such as the webhook you are trying to get data from and the error that is returned. I did find a few resources that should help you for now:
https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00004hYtrQSAS/how-to-create-webhook-receivers-in-net-core-21
https://dev.to/ijason/bigcommerce--creating-a-webhook-4j6o
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52516378/custom-webhook-receiver-in-net-core-2-1

Comment: hi 
i am create the webhook in big commerce for product delete. My destination URl not hit so i don't getting any error

Comment: i am following the above URl
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52516378/custom-webhook-receiver-in-net-core-2-1
according to sasi reka his code is working but i follow the same code not working for me